# Omitting XML processing instruction when serializing an object

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, visual-studio-2003

I'm serializing an object in a C# VS2003 / .Net 1.1 application. I need it serialized without the processing instruction, however. The XmlSerializer class puts out something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<MyObject>
    <Property1>Data</Property1>
    <Property2>More Data</Property2>
</MyObject>
```

Is there any way to get something like the following, without processing the resulting text to remove the tag?

```
<MyObject>
    <Property1>Data</Property1>
    <Property2>More Data</Property2>
</MyObject>
```

For those that are curious, my code looks like this...

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

using ( TextWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder) )
{
    serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, comments);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following link will take you to a post where someone has a method of supressing the processing instruction by using an XmlWriter and getting into an 'Element' state rather than a 'Start' state. This causes the processing instruction to not be written.

[Suppress Processing Instruction](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.webservices/2004-03/0315.html)

> If you pass an XmlWriter to the serializer, it will only emit a processing 
>   instruction if the XmlWriter's state is 'Start' (i.e., has not had anything 
>   written to it yet).

```
// Assume we have a type named 'MyType' and a variable of this type named 
'myObject' 
System.Text.StringBuilder output = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 
System.IO.StringWriter internalWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(output); 
System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(internalWriter); 
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new 
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType)); 


writer.WriteStartElement("MyContainingElement"); 
serializer.Serialize(writer, myObject); 
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

> In this case, the writer will be in a state of 'Element' (inside an element) 
>   so no processing instruction will be written. One you finish writing the 
>   XML, you can extract the text from the underlying stream and process it to 
>   your heart's content.

Comment: But this still requires post-processing the result to remove the MyContainingElement start and end tags, no?
Although at least they will be known, so that's good...

Comment: I played with this and replaced WriteStartElement with WriteRaw("") and got rid of the WriteEndElement - then all I needed to do to get good output was TrimStart() the BOM off. Cool!

Answer (score 10):

I made a small correction

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
using ( XmlWriter stringWriter = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings) )
{   
   serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, comments);  
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In 2.0, you would use [XmLWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration.aspx), and serialize to an XmlWriter - however I don't think this exists in 1.1; so not *entirely* useful - but just one more "consider upgrading" thing... and yes, I realise it isn't always possible.

Answer (score 1):

What about omitting namespaces ?

instead of using

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                namespaces.Add("", "");
```

ex:

```
<message xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927/omitting-namespace-when-serializing-an-object

Answer (score 0):

If by "processing instruction" you mean the xml declaration, then you can avoid this by setting the OmitXmlDeclaration property of XmlWriterSettings.  You'll need to serialize using an XmlWriter, to accomplish this.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

using ( XmlWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder, settings) )
{
    serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, comments);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

But ah, this doesn't answer your question for 1.1.  Well, for reference to others.

Answer (score 0):

This works in .NET 1.1.  (But you should still consider upgrading)

```
    XmlSerializer s1= new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass)); 
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add( "", "" );


    MyClass c= new MyClass();
    c.PropertyFromDerivedClass= "Hallo";

    sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    s1.Serialize(new XTWND(sw), c, ns);
    ....

   /// XmlTextWriterFormattedNoDeclaration
   /// helper class : eliminates the XML Documentation at the
   /// start of a XML doc. 
   /// XTWFND = XmlTextWriterFormattedNoDeclaration
   public class XTWFND : System.Xml.XmlTextWriter
   {
     public XTWFND(System.IO.TextWriter w) : base(w) { Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented; }
     public override void WriteStartDocument() { }
   }
```