# Deserialize XML without namespaces but in a class expecting namespaces

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

> Duplicate:
>   [Omitting all xml namespaces when serializing an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927/)
>   Not the same.. I want in the other way: Deserialize!

---

I have a C# class as bellow:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("NFe", Namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class TNFe
{

    private TNFeInfNFe infNFeField;

    private SignatureType signatureField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public TNFeInfNFe infNFe
    { ...
```

I use this class to serialize/deserialize XML files by user request.
But I've got a problem: namespaces definition were added on the new version of this software.
The XML is still the same, only adding namespaces definition.

Eg., last version...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <NFe>
    <infNFe version="1.10">
      ...
```

and new version...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <infNFe version="2.10">
      ...
```

I need to load XML files with and without these namespaces.
I have a lot of nested classes and each of it has its own namespaces definition.

**I would like to use the same classes for both XML, with and without namespaces.**

I tried to create an XmlTextReader and overwrite the NamespaceURI method, but I still receives an exception with no much info. I think .NET engine is trying to force the class namespace definition against the XML.

Comment: Hi, is your query resolved?

Comment: Arijit, I solved it using a different approach. Unfortunately there is no way to do what I wanted the way I wanted (using less code as possible). So I used XmlTextReader for some webservices and on others I serialized the whole Xml in a string and removed the unused namespaces by using String.Replace. Not the best thing ever, but it has proved to be good also.

Comment: Thanks for the response, well actually my problem is looking similar to you, the answer given below is not working I guess.
Can you show how you did it?
It's being 4 years why microsoft didn't thought of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had run into a similar challenge with a proxy class. For reasons that I won't go into, I needed to serialize the class manually using the XmlSerializer on web server and deserialize on client. I was not able to find an elegant solution online, so I just avoided the issue by removing the XmlTypeAttribute from the proxy class manually after I auto-generated it in Visual Studio.

I kept coming back to see if there was a way to get the namespace to workout. Here is how I got it working without the need to modify the auto-generated classes. I ended up using an XmlTextReader to return the desired namespace on nodes matching a property name. There is room for improvement, but i hope it helps someone.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create list to serialize
        Person personA = new Person() { Name = "Bob", Age = 10, StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1960"), Money = 123456m };
        List<Person> listA = new List<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            listA.Add(personA);
        }

        //serialize list to file
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("Test.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, listA);
        writer.Close();

        //deserialize list from file
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ProxysNamespace.Person>));
        List<ProxysNamespace.Person> listB;
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream("Test.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            //configure proxy reader
            XmlSoapProxyReader reader = new XmlSoapProxyReader(file);
            reader.ProxyNamespace = "http://myappns.com/";      //the namespace of the XmlTypeAttribute 
            reader.ProxyType = typeof(ProxysNamespace.Person); //the type with the XmlTypeAttribute

            //deserialize
            listB = (List<ProxysNamespace.Person>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        //display list
        foreach (ProxysNamespace.Person p in listB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Money { get; set; }
}

namespace ProxysNamespace
{
    [XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://myappns.com/")]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public decimal Money { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}:{1},{2:d}:{3:c2}", Name, Age, Birthday, Money);
        }
    }
}

public class XmlSoapProxyReader : XmlTextReader
{
    List<object> propNames;
    public XmlSoapProxyReader(Stream input)
        : base(input)
    {
        propNames = new List<object>();
    }

    public string ProxyNamespace { get; set; }

    private Type proxyType;
    public Type ProxyType
    {
        get { return proxyType; }
        set
        {
            proxyType = value;
            PropertyInfo[] properties = proxyType.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
            {
                propNames.Add(p.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public override string NamespaceURI
    {
        get
        {
            object localname = LocalName;
            if (propNames.Contains(localname))
                return ProxyNamespace;
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi GLass, I'm almost into a similar problem, need some help

Answer (score 9):

In order to deserialize XML without namespace add XmlRoot attribute to the class that represents the top of your hierarchy:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="plugins", Namespace="")]
```

In my example the Xml has no namespace and starts like

```
<plugins><...
```

The class that it deserializes to:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="plugins", Namespace="")]
public class Plugins
{
   //...
}
```

Obviously, your situation may be a slightly different, but this code works for me:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
   XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);                
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Plugins));
   var plugins = (Plugins)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

-Stan

Answer (score 1):

You could read the file in as text, remove the offending namespace text, then deserialize it.

You may need to write the "good" text back into a [memory/string/etc] stream so that the XmlSerializer's Deserialize can be called.

Comment: Yes... this seems to be the "best" way. Tks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement IXmlSerializable to improve your custom serialization.

Comment: I have lots of nested classes. Would be terrible to implement it on each of these classes just to remove the namespaces!!!!
I would have to add a XmlSchemaProvider for each class, returning different schemas depending on the version.

Isn't there an easier way to do deserialize? Just like adding an empty namespace string to the serialize function?