# Unqualifing a xml in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

Is there an smart way of unqualifing (clean namespaces references) a XML in c#? All the xml references the same schema.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to [Omitting all xml namespaces when serializing an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927) provide 3 different ways to do it.