# TRICKY Question about List<T> to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a tricky question regarding shallow serialization of List of objects

my entities

```
public class Requests
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public Meta MetaType { get; set; }

}

public class Meta
{
    public string MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Shallow serialization using XMLSerializer

```
    List<Requests> lstXML = new List<Requests>();

    Requests xml = new Requests();
    xml.Action = "INSERT";
    xml.MetaType = new Meta { IpAddress = "192.2.3.4", MerchantId = "DALE", Version = "1" };
    lstXML.Add(xml);
    xml = new Requests();
    xml.Action = "UPDATE";
    xml.MetaType = new Meta { IpAddress = "192.2.3.40", MerchantId = "SECD", Version = "1" };
    lstXML.Add(xml);


    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\XML\test.txt"))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Requests>));
        serializer.Serialize(sw, lstXML);

    }
```

output textfile text.txt

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ArrayOfRequests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Requests>
  <Action>INSERT</Action>
   <MetaType>
  <MerchantId>DALE</MerchantId>
  <IpAddress>192.2.3.4</IpAddress>
  <Version>1</Version>
</MetaType>
   </Requests>
 <Requests>
<Action>UPDATE</Action>
<MetaType>
  <MerchantId>SECD</MerchantId>
  <IpAddress>192.2.3.40</IpAddress>
  <Version>1</Version>
</MetaType>
     </Requests>
    </ArrayOfRequests>
```

> now my problem is
>
> 1) I need to remove the < ?XML
>   version="1.0" ....> and the
>   < ArrayOfRequests ...>
>    tag and retain only
>   the XML tag of my Entities. How can I
>   do that?
>
> 2) How can I CAPITALIZE(CAPS) the
>   Element Name ( -> 
>   ) in the output textfile?

my desired textfile output would be

```
<XML>
 <REQUESTS>
 <ACTION>INSERT</ACTION>
 <META>
   <MERCHANTID>DALE</MERCHANTID>
   <IPADDRESS>202.164.178.163</IPADDRESS>
   <VERSION>1</VERSION>
 </META>
 <REQUESTS>

 <REQUESTS>
 <ACTION>INSERT</ACTION>
 <META>
   <MERCHANTID>DALE</MERCHANTID>
   <IPADDRESS>202.164.178.163</IPADDRESS>
   <VERSION>1</VERSION>
 </META>
 <REQUESTS>

 </XML>
```

Thanks in advance guys! =)

Comment: You'd have more success if you asked the two separate questions, as separate questions!

Comment: The `<?xml... ?>` tag is mandatory, without it your XML document isn't valid...

Comment: And anyway, you can only have 1 root element, so with the format you want the document can't contain more than 1 Requests object

Comment: my bad actualy the root element would be <XML></XML> and yes there would be more than 1 request tag

Comment: @Thomas my output file is not an XML but, a textfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
[XmlType("REQUESTS")]  
public class Requests
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ACTION")]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="META")]
    public Meta MetaType { get; set; }
    ...

}

public class Meta
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName="MERCHANTID")]
    public string MerchantId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Requests>), new XmlRootAttribute("XML"));
```

Comment: thanks! works fine except for the Root Element, <XML></XML> doesnt appear on the textfile...

Comment: do you have "XML" as the second parameter to the XmlSerializer?

Comment: yup var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Requests>), "XML");

Comment: the "XML" is in the <ArrayOfREQUEST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="XML"> element.

Comment: what appears as the root element then?

Comment: the "XML" goes to the xmlns attribute of the <ArrayOfREQUEST> tag

Comment: root element is <ArrayOfREQUEST xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; xmlns="XML">

Comment: @CSharpNoob  my bad. check out my edit on the last line. it should be new XmlRootAttribute("XML") instead of just "XML"

Comment: thanks much, it works, however it still has the xmlns:xsi attribute.... <XML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></XML>, is there anyway to remove that attributes without manually manipulating the string of the textfile? I just need <XML></XML> tag, thanks much

Comment: @CSharpNoob check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927/omitting-all-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-when-serializing-an-object-in-net

Comment: thank you very much dude! save a lot of work, it's 12am here i can finally go home =)

Answer (score 1):

So, you don't want XML serialization. You want a custom approximation of it. Therefore, you're probably going to have to write it yourself. Are you using any kind of templating language? If you know the types that you'll be serializing up-front, a templating system will help you immensely. If you don't know the types beforehand, next answer please.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute simplest solution would probably to process the string, as currently generated, with a couple of post-processing steps:

```
// Stream to a string instead of directly to the file
yourString = // stream XML here.

// Remove the xmlns stuff.
yourString = yourString.Replace(
          " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"", 
          ""); 

// Upper-case the start-elements and end-elements (your data has no attributes, 
// so keep it simple)
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, 
                           "<\{0,1}([^>]+)>", 
                           delegate(Match m) 
                           {
                               return m.Value.ToUpper(); 
                           });
```

Comment: thanks for answering the 2nd question, I also think its the only solution since XmlSerializer automatically creates the xmlns captions...