# understanding xmlns tags in a WCF response

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to modify a WCF service and i have problems understanding namespaces and xmlns tags in my response.

This dataType is in the Iservice file, and has a tag for the namespace:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "3.0.4506.2152")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.zz.com/x/Domain")]
public partial class DiscrepancyType
{

    private string barcodeField;

    private string classificationField;

    private bool commentRequiredField;

    private string descriptionField;

    private int discrepancyTypeIdField;

    private System.Nullable<int> usageRankField;

    private string useCaseIdField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string Barcode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.barcodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.barcodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string Classification
    {
        get
        {
            return this.classificationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.classificationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    public bool CommentRequired
    {
        get
        {
            return this.commentRequiredField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.commentRequiredField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=4)]
    public int DiscrepancyTypeId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.discrepancyTypeIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.discrepancyTypeIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=5)]
    public System.Nullable<int> UsageRank
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usageRankField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.usageRankField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=6)]
    public string UseCaseId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.useCaseIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.useCaseIdField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the response, i get the following result. I don't understand why i get the xlmns tag in each attribute, i would want to only have that domain in the DiscrepancyType tag. How can i fix this?

```
<DiscrepancyType>
               <Barcode xmlns="http://www.zz.com/x/Domain"></Barcode>
               <Classification xmlns="http://www.zz.com/x/Domain"></Classification>
               <CommentRequired xmlns="http://www.zz.com/x/Domain"></CommentRequired>
               <Description xmlns="http://www.zz.com/x/Domain"></Description>
               <DiscrepancyTypeId xmlns="http://www.zz.com/x/Domain"></DiscrepancyTypeId>
               <UsageRank xmlns="http://www.zz.com/x/Domain"></UsageRank>
               <UseCaseId xmlns="http://www.zz.com/x/Domain"></UseCaseId>
</DiscrepancyType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Omitting all xsi and xsd namespaces when serializing an object in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927/omitting-all-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-when-serializing-an-object-in-net)

The most important section is to clear namespace while serializing. Example serializing method could look like:

```
public string Serialize()
{
  var writer = new StringWriter();
  var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
  ns.Add("", "");

  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DiscrepancyType));
  serializer.Serialize(writer, this, ns);
  return writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I think the WCF server is doing the serializing itself, there is no code for this i can find?

Answer (score 0):

It's behavior by default. Do you have some problems with namespaces? You can remove the XML namespace by setting the Namespace parameter of the DataContract attribute to an empty string

Comment: We have two versions of a server, the only difference is that the response of server A has the xlmns in DiscrepancyType tag, server B has it in each attribute tag in DiscrepancyType. The client can parse the response from Server A but not Server B. I can't access the source code to server A.

Comment: I think you can try to play with ContractNamespaceAttribute for the Barcode,Classification e.t.c E.g. set ContractNamespaceAttribute to empty string value. I am not sure and haven't posibility to check this now, but I think it might help