# How to convert Object to XML Without Namespace?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code, how I can remove the namespace from output xml

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderTable));
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, null);
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, ot);
string result = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());



<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <OrderTable xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ForceUpdate>false</ForceUpdate> 
  <TableId xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <UpdatedBy>Jack</UpdatedBy> 
  </OrderTable>
```

I want to remove xmlns, I googled, but those are not helping me.

Comment: 'the namespace'?  What namespace?  Either way, this is almost certainly duplicate.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I am sending that xml to a rest service which expect plain xml without namespaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Omitting all xsi and xsd namespaces when serializing an object in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927/omitting-all-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-when-serializing-an-object-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove xmlns

All you have to do is using `XmlSerializerNamespaces`

```
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, ot, ns);
```