# Remove namespace xml of a property during XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a object like this:

```
public class A {
 public int ID {get; set;} 
 public Name PName {get; set;} 
}

[XmlType(Namespace = "somenamespace")]
public class Name{
 public string FName {get; set;}
 public string LName {get; set;}
}
```

When I serialize this I get below XML:

```
<A>
 <ID>1</ID>
 <PName>
  <FName xmlns="somenamespace">First Name</FNAME>
  <LName xmlns="somenamespace">Last Name</LNAME>
 </PName>
</A>
```

Is there a way to get rid of the namespace of class "Name" during the serialization?

Obviously I cannot just remove XML type attribute of class "Name".

I have already tried this solution (first answer), but it did not work for me. [Omitting all xsi and xsd namespaces when serializing an object in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927/omitting-all-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-when-serializing-an-object-in-net)

Many thanks in advance,

Ash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't own the type `Name`, you can still control its serialisation by overriding the XML attributes using [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides?view=netframework-4.7.2) when creating the serialiser.

For example:

```
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

overrides.Add(typeof(Name), new XmlAttributes());

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(A), overrides, null, null, string.Empty);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f9QzwE) for a working demo.